# Cant perform post request with HTTPParams Object

Tags: angular, http

I am new to Angular and have problems getting data from a server using the Angular httpClient and HttpParams.

The whole uri specifying works, however this is not my desired solution. I try to get it work with the HttpParams Object.

I am using Angular6

In following code snippets only the HttpParams are different

Following code works:

```js
addBidirectionalSynonym(dialectLanguage: string, entryId1: string, entryId2: string) {


    this.http
      .post("http://localhost:8090/dialect/addBidirectionalSynonyms?dialectLanguage=tirolerisch&id1=5d1221893269a28de043edaf&id2=5d1221923269a28de043edb1", { ///dialectLanguage=tirolerisch

      })
      .toPromise()
      .then((data: any) => {

      })
// catch Block is the same in both examples
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.status === 200 || err.status === 201) {
          console.log("Created entry. ", err.status);

          return;
        }

        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          console.error("You may have no internet connection");
        }
        if (err.status === 500) {
          console.error("Server error. Please contact admin", err.status);
        }
        return;
      });
  }
```

Following Code doesn't work:

```js
  addBidirectionalSynonym(dialectLanguage: string, entryId1: string, entryId2: string) {
    console.log("inserting synonym::::::", dialectLanguage, entryId1, entryId2);


    let params1 = new HttpParams()
      .set("dialectLanguage", dialectLanguage)
      .set("id1", entryId1)
      .set("id2", entryId2);
    console.warn("params: ", params1);

    this.http
      .post("http://localhost:8090/dialect/addBidirectionalSynonyms", { 
        params: params1
      })
      .toPromise()
      .then((data: any) => {

      })
// catch Block is the same in both examples
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.status === 200 || err.status === 201) {
          console.log("Created entry. ", err.status);

          return;
        }

        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          console.error("You may have no internet connection");
        }
        if (err.status === 500) {
          console.error("Server error. Please contact admin", err.status);
        }
        return;
      });
  }
```

The http method gets called like this:

```js
  this.service.addBidirectionalSynonym(this.data.language, this.data.dialectId, row.dialect.dialectId);
```

failure message on server:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'dialectLanguage' is not present
```

generated url from Client:

```js
{"params":{"updates":[{"param":"dialectLanguage","value":"tirolerisch","op":"s"},{"param":"id1","value":"5d12218d3269a28de043edb0","op":"s"},{"param":"id2","value":"5d12219c3269a28de043edb3","op":"s"}],"cloneFrom":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"encoder":{},"map":null}}
```

i don't know what this "op" should be for

Comment: Which version of Angular  are u using

Comment: sry, I forgot to mention: Angular 6

Comment: what is the URL of the request generated by your 2nd approach? (Check network tab in devtools)

Comment: {"params":{"updates":[{"param":"dialectLanguage","value":"tirolerisch","op":"s"},{"param":"id1","value":"5d12218d3269a28de043edb0","op":"s"},{"param":"id2","value":"5d12219c3269a28de043edb3","op":"s"}],"cloneFrom":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"encoder":{},"map":null}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your first approach, the paramters should be in URL like: `/addBidirectionalSynonyms?dialectLanguage=tirolerisch&...`.

In your second approach `this.http.post(endpointUrl, {params: params1})`, you pass a body to the HTTP POST but no in-url parameters.

To do what you want you need to do the following:

```js
this.http
  .post("http://localhost:8090/dialect/addBidirectionalSynonyms", null, { 
                                                                  ^^^^^
    params: params1
   })
   ...
```

Because you don't have an HTTP body.

Check the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) for more infos.